# How to recycle memory of c++ unordered_map on windows

Tags: stl, unordered-map

I know malloc_trim works on linux, is there any similar function on window?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples and oranges here. `std::unordered_map` is a higher level container, which somewhere in its guts uses the `new` and `delete` C++ operators to allocate and free memory.  Those operators internally may, or may not happen to rely on libc `malloc`, but you must not make any assumptions about that. However `malloc_trim` is a GNU extension to the libc.

If the C++ runtime being used goes go via `malloc` for allocation, then `malloc_trim` will work here, as well.

The proper question to ask would be: *Are there vendor specific extensions to commonly used C++ runtime, that do for `new`/`delete` what `malloc_trim` does for Glibc `malloc`?*

Either way, the real question is: Why do you care? There's a high probability that over the whole lifetime of a process, after a certain "warm up" period has passed, the *active* size of the memory arena of a typical allocator implementation will have stabilized, and is close to the optimal size of the program being run. Also keep in mind, that the size of the virtual memory mapping of arena may be a lot larger, than what's actually physically mapped. It's perfectly possible on a 64 bit machine to have a virtual set size of hundreds of Terabytes, yet only a couple of kilobytes of that actually in the resident set.